# Keeping attribute data when exporting KML to feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.0, data, kml, google-earth

I am working on updating kml files into an mxd. I am able to use the conversion tool to change each KML to a layer file, but I am unable to keep the original kml attribute data. When I export point files, it exports as one single point instead of multiple points which does not make sense to me.

Is there a way convert KML/KMZs to a feature class and keep all of the original data?

Comment: The tool will convert any of the snippet information you have into an HTML popup. What further attributes do you have in the KML that arent converting? Or could you provide an example of your particular KML?

Comment: you want kml_name to get the attribute from the kml.

Comment: None of the attributes are converting from my kml. I am working on exporting a google file of hurricane evac routes and points of disaster. The roads export as lines, but do not have road names attached to them. Likewise, the points of disaster are exporting as one single point

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Convert GPS Files to Shapefiles toolbox.](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Map-Template-Gallery/details?entryID=BC061D5E-1422-2418-7FCE-CC0FBB0C0825)  Also, if you have ArcView 3.3 you could use the [KML to SHP script](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14988).