# Import KML attributes into the correct schema

Tags: arcgis-10.1, kml, data-interoperability

I have a kml file containing over 4000 polygons with attributes which must be retained (in 3 different fields). After using the standard `KML to Layer` tool, all the attributes are now in one `PopupInfo` field, along with the html code.

I have the `Data Interoperability` extension, so after looking at the questions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10611/keeping-attribute-data-when-exporting-kml-to-feature-class) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/how-to-convert-kml-to-shapefile-without-losing-attributes), I came across a [post on the ArcGIS forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/26385-Best-way-to-import-KML-with-attributes?p=114257&viewfull=1#post114257):

> The Data Interoperability extension will read KML (including folders and subfolders) and use any schema object defining the attributes. Thus what it writes out will have the correct field definitions. The same goes for writing KML with a schema object, given geodatabase inputs.

What I understand from that is that using the `Quick Import` tool will read the KML and export it to a gdb based on a schema which I defined. This seems to  be exactly what I want, except I cannot find the option to specify the schema.

I exposed the `kml_name` attribute as mentioned in the other question, but the field remained empty. I tried downloading the KML2shapefile plugin with MapWindow, but it is only for 32 bit and I am running 64 bit. I am unable to download the FME trial at work.

Comment: The required data can be read out of the PopupInfo field by using Python to split the string at the various HTML tags, retrieving the data between them and using an update cursor to populate the relevant fields in the feature class.

Answer (score 1):

You might try loading your kml into QGIS then saving it out as a shapefile.  It's not going to place all those data into Popupinfo.